# Trouble in writing a pandas Dataframe to excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of excel files, I am creating dataframes from them. I perform few tasks on the dataframes and then try to write these dataframes back into the file(more like replacing them entirely). But I am unable to write the files.

Here is the code

```
for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    table = pd.read_excel(file, 0)
    ## (Perform Operations here)          
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file)
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save
```

Now when I try to read the file back into pandas I am getting this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test2.xlsx'
```

There are no files being created anywhere. But I am unable to tell where am I going wrong. 
Also `writer.save` returns

```
<bound method _XlsxWriter.save of <pandas.io.excel._XlsxWriter object at 0x000000000B9712E8>>
```

Comment: `writer.save()` not `writer.save`? Just `writer.save` is the method and you need to call it from it to do the saving.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. Now it works alright

Comment: Just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `write.save` without the parentheses. This would have worked if `.save` was just an `attribute`. But since it is a `method`, it needs to be called with the parentheses for any effect to occur. Therefore, you should change your code to the following:

```
for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    table = pd.read_excel(file, 0)
    ## (Perform Operations here)          
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file)
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

I hope this helps.